# GIMP Package broken, Ubuntu Software centre not working

Tags: dependencies, gimp, package-management

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and have installed GIMP last night. But today, my update manager is showing that your system has broken packages and dependencies. When I try to install the GIMP update that is available in the update manager, following error occurs.

**The package system is broken**

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 gimp: Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.24.0-2 is installed
       Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.13-20ubuntu5 is installed
       Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.8.0-3ubuntu2 is installed
       Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.24.0-1ubuntu1 is installed
       Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.30.0-0ubuntu4 is installed
       Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.20.0) but 2.24.6-0ubuntu5 is installed
       Depends: libjpeg62 (>= 6b1) but 6b1-1ubuntu2 is installed
       Depends: librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4) but 2.34.1-2 is installed
       Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu3 is installed
       Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but 2.7.2-7ubuntu2 is installed
```

Then I tried to run various commands from Terminal and following errors pop up.

```
randomhero@randomhero-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for randomhero: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gimp
Suggested packages:
  gimp-help-en gimp-help libgimp-perl gimp-gap gimp-console
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gimp
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,388 kB of archives.
After this operation, 324 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 213862 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace gimp 2.6.11-2ubuntu4 (using .../gimp_2.7.4-2011102201~oo_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gimp ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.7.4-2011102201~oo_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-xmc', which is also in package gimp-plugin-registry 3.5.4-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.7.4-2011102201~oo_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The Update Manager shows GIMP update under Other Updates(LP-PPA-matthaeus123-mrw-gimp-svn )
Is that official repository? Do I need to remove that repository? If yes, how?

Also the Ubuntu Software Center pops up error saying "Items cannot be installed or removed until package catalog is repaired."

When I click repair, it again gives me following error.

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
p    erl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 213862 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace gimp 2.6.11-2ubuntu4 (using .../gimp_2.7.4-2011102201~oo_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gimp ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.7.4-2011102201~oo_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-xmc', which is also in package gimp-plugin-registry 3.5.4-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.7.4-2011102201~oo_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to remove gimp package with sudo apt-get remove gimp, but it shows following error.

```
randomhero@randomhero-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo apt-get remove gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp-gmic : Depends: gimp (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
 gimp-paint-studio : Depends: gimp but it is not going to be installed
 gimp-plugin-registry : Depends: gimp (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I don't know how to go ahead and fix this error. I need to install few applications, but I can't because of these errors. I don't want the GIMP software as such, I just installed just in case. But I want my Ubuntu Software Center to work.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to eliminate `gimp-paint-studio , gimp-gmic , and gimp-plugin-registry`to fix your last issue.

`sudo apt-get remove gimp-paint-studio gimp-gmic gimp-plugin-registry`

For repository , use `apt-add-repository -r ppa:user/repository` to remove one

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed the issue with Synaptic. It took care of everything when I removed GIMP. I had tried to remove those paint studio and registry things, but they were giving me same error. :\

Answer (score 2):

If you *did* want to install gimp from that PPA, its webpage (https://launchpad.net/~matthaeus123/+archive/mrw-gimp-svn) has the solution:

> GIMP 2.7.5 Will not work with the current glib and gtk in Oneiric. To
>   fix the problem install these repos
>
> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu oneiric main
>
> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/testing/ubuntu oneiric main

Answer (score 2):

I'll tell you what worked for me.

Remove form repository manager these 3 PPAs:

**http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu**
**http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/testing/ubuntu**
**http://ppa.launchpad.net/matthaeus123/mrw-gimp-svn/ubuntu**

Because it has a wrong dependency list for Oneiric (libglib2.0).

And remove gimpdata from Synaptics remaining from provious install attempts.

Then add this PPA from command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jmou/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

This will install GIMP 2.7.4.

I don't know how to fix de wrong PPA package for Oneiric.

Hope this helps.